# Symfony3 Ошибка в форме

Tags: symfony

При создании формы получаю ошибку.
Expected argument of type "string", "AppBundle\Form\BookType" given

500 Internal Server Error - UnexpectedTypeException

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $book = new Book();
    $form = $this->createForm(new BookType(), $book);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($book);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('book_show', array('id' => $book->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('book/new.html.twig', array(
        'book' => $book,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

class BookType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Book::class,
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'book_form';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Symfony3 теперь нельзя передавать `FormType` как объект, всегда необходимо передавать полное название класса. В вашем случае вам надо передать так

```
$form = $this->createForm(BookType::class, $book);
```